# Hive QL Collection items terminated by '$'

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am creating an external table customer with customer id, name and spouse name.

```
 CREATE TABLE customer(cust id, name struct<fname:string,lname:string>,spouse_name struct<fname:string,lname:string>
    )row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    collection items terminated by '$';
```

I am wondering what if incoming data comes something like this

```
1,FNAME1$LNAME1,SPOUSE_FNAME1#SPOUSE_LNAME1
2,FNAME2$LNAME2,SPOUSE_FNAME2#SPOUSE_LNAME2
```

I cannot have two delimiters in 'collection items' statement. '$' delimiter would only separate FNAME* and LNAME*. It won't do anything with SPOUSE_FNAME* and SPOUSE_LNAME*. Do we need to write a custom serde for this? I am not sure how data would look like in real world but it is very possible that at some point of time we can get data like this.

Comment: Data processing is something that should be carefully planned and managed. It is also possible that text fields will contain signs as `,`,`$` or `#`. The "will get what we get and deal with it when time comes" approach, won't take you far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE customer(cust_id int, name String, spouse_name string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
load data inpath '<hdfs path of input file>' overwrite into table customer;

CREATE external TABLE customer_tmp(cust_id int, name string,spouse_name string)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
stored as textfile location '/hdfs_location_of_customer_tmp'; 

insert overwrite table customer_tmp
select cust_id,regexp_replace(name,'\\W\\b',':') as name,regexp_replace(spouse_name,'\\W\\b',':') as spouse_name from customer; 

CREATE TABLE customer_final(cust_id int, name struct<fname:string,lname:string>,spouse_name struct<fname:string,lname:string>)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by ':' 
stored as textfile;

load data inpath '/hdfs_location_of_customer_tmp/*' overwrite into table customer_final;
```

*Kindly don't forget to let us know if it worked :)*

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is loading the structs as simple strings and doing the data manipulation within a view.

```
create external table customer
(
    cust_id     int 
   ,name        string
   ,spouse_name string
) 
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
;
```

---

```
select * from customer
;
```

---

```
+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| cust_id |     name      |         spouse_name         |
+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|       1 | FNAME1$LNAME1 | SPOUSE_FNAME1#SPOUSE_LNAME1 |
|       2 | FNAME2$LNAME2 | SPOUSE_FNAME2#SPOUSE_LNAME2 |
+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

---

```
create view customer_v
as
select  cust_id
       ,named_struct('fname',name[0]       ,'lname',name[1])        as name
       ,named_struct('fname',spouse_name[0],'lname',spouse_name[1]) as spouse_name

from   (select  cust_id
               ,split(name,'\\$')       as name
               ,split(spouse_name,'#')  as spouse_name

        from    customer
        ) c
;
```

---

```
select * from customer_v
;
```

---

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| cust_id |                name                 |                    spouse_name                    |
+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | {"fname":"FNAME1","lname":"LNAME1"} | {"fname":"SPOUSE_FNAME1","lname":"SPOUSE_LNAME1"} |
|       2 | {"fname":"FNAME2","lname":"LNAME2"} | {"fname":"SPOUSE_FNAME2","lname":"SPOUSE_LNAME2"} |
+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```